# jQuery UI Datepicker field specific formatting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm looking for a way to tell Datepicker to format the date a specific way for only a single field? I was hoping some sort of INPUT inline options can be set somehow to format for that specific field and leave all others the exact same.

I have found the formatting options:
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

But of course that is for initial setting. I need to be able to tell it just for a specific field to be only the Year for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dateFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) option for a specific jQuery UI date picker/instance.

Code:

```
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy' });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dyvH2/

Comment: As I asked above, I need it to be inline in the field if possible. I know I can do that, instantiate for another field ID or Class rather than the default. But I'm looking for something inline.

Answer (score 0):

When initializing a plugin across many elements but need specific config based on element instance is easy to do it by initializing them individually within an `each` loop

```
 /* loop over collection of elements*/
$('.datePickerClass').each(function(){

   var opts={/* your standard config, or leave as empty object if using all defaults*/ }

   /* check some condition to isolate special cases*/
   if( $(this).is('.datePickerSpecial') ){
     /* modify config for this condition*/
     $.extend( opts, {dateFormat : "d M, y"});
   }
  /* initialize current instance*/
   $(this).datepicker(opts);

})
```

Taking this a step or 2 further you could easily turn this into it's own plugin. You could also use `data-` attributes to pass different config settings in for the `$.extend`